# Read *.tar.gz file in python without extracting

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

In python 3, I am trying to read files that resides in a tar.gz archive without extracting them (meaning without writing the extract files to disk). I found the tarfile module, and this is what I wrote (much simplified):

```
tar = tarfile.open('arhivename.tar.gz',encoding='utf-8')
for x in tar.getmembers():
    filelikeobject=tar.extractfile(x)
    #pass the filelikeobject to a third party function that accepts file-like object that read strings

    #the following lines are for debug:
    r=filelikeobject.read()
    print(type(r).__name__) #prints out 'bytes' - need 'str'
```

the problem is, the tar.extractfile(x) returns a file object that returns bytes when calling read(). I need it to return str using utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `tarfile.open`,

```
tarfile.open('arhivename.tar.gz', encoding='utf-8')
```

The `encoding` parameter controls the encoding of the filenames, not the encoding of the file contents. It doesn't make sense for the `encoding` parameter to control the encoding of the file contents, because different files inside the tar file can be encoded differently. So, a tar file really just contains binary data.

You can decode this data by wrapping the file with the UTF-8 stream reader from the `codecs` module:

```
import codecs
utf8reader = codecs.getreader('utf-8')
for name in tar.getmembers():
    fp = utf8reader(tar.extractfile(name))
```